# Jquery change html after select box changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the following jquery, when an option is selected some HTML will be added or another one based on an if else statement, that works right, the problem is that once one option is selected, if i go back and change that option, the HTML added will not change, but if i add an alert, the alert do change based on the value name of the option box, so i dont understand exactly why it doesnt change the html based on the change() jquery function.

here is the code

```
$("select").change(function() {

 option = $("#opcion").val();

if(option == "celulares") {
$(".insert").replaceWith( " <div class='row' id='option2'> <div      class='col-xs-6'>Por favor ingrese el costo de cada celular en dolares: </div><div class='col-xs-6'><form class='form-inline'><div class='form-group'><label class='sr-only' for='exampleInputAmount'>Amount (in dollars)</label><div class='input-group'><div class='input-group-addon'>$</div><input type='text' class='form-control' id='costoproducto' placeholder='Monto'><div class='input-group-addon'>.00</div></div></div><div id='validacioncosto'></div></form></div></div><hr> " + 
  "<div class='row' id='option6'><div class='col-xs-6' id='resultado'></div><div class='col-xs-6'><button type='button' id='calculo' class='btn btn-warning'>Calcular</button></div></div><div class='row' id='result'></div> "); 

} else if(option == "electronica" || option == "juguetes" || option == "repuestos" || option == "otro") {
$(".insert").replaceWith(option);
alert(option);
}
});
```

and the HTML

```
 <option></option>                   
 <option value="celulares">Celulares</option>
 <option value="electronica">Electronica</option>
 <option value="juguetes">Juguetes</option>
 <option value="repuestos">Repuestos</option>
 <option value="otro">Otro</option>

</select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div class="insert">
        <p>hola</p>
    </div>
```

any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceWith` function replaces the element by the new HTML. So after then, you won't be able to select it anymore because the HTML you used doesn't have the `insert` class. I presume you wanted to the function `html` like this :

`$(".insert").html( YOUR_HTML);`

Comment: thank you, that solved the issue and your great explanation made me understand the why, i always though that replaceWith() only changed the inside of the div and not removing the name itself, so for this to work with replacewith i had to also include the div in the code inserted, which is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off using `$(".insert").html()` instead of `$(".insert").replace()` so that you're just switching out the guts of the div.